# Is there any function available which return marker information?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm new to google maps and I'm working on a project. I am looking for a function which will provide location related information of the marker in google maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to combine the functionality of [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) and [Infowindow of Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple), the process would be when an user enters a place, the geocoding API will get the information of the location then set the marker based on the coordinates given by the Geocoding API then supply the other details in the infowindow about the details of the place. Samples can be seen in the documentations.

Comment: Kindly also include some codes of what you've done so far to prevent being downvoted and for the community to understand your use case better :)